# my localhost IIS display me my project files

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7

I try to launch or browse my asp.Net mvc project on IIS, and he gives an error 403- forbidden, I solved this problem with enable the Directory Browsing, but after that he displays me my folders of the project.

[image: The error]

Comment: This folder contains your source files, so not the one you should deploy to IIS. You have to read the official guide to learn how to publish such a web app, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/web-deployment-in-the-enterprise/building-and-packaging-web-application-projects

Answer (score 0):

It's because of no default page in your directory refer below article

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/francissvk/set-default-page-for-a-website-in-iis421/

If you having MVC application then you need to set default route and make sure you have MVC framework installed on the server

```
'routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters*
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", 
        id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);'
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I have a default route and MVC framework is installed

Comment: Add below line in project.json"publishOptions": {
"include": [
  "wwwroot",
  "Views",
  "appsettings.json",
  "web.config"
]

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the correct default documents set in IIS?

1. Open IIS (Windows key+R and type inetmgr)
2. Select the Default Documents option
3. Enter the default page name in the order you want IIS to check (index.html index.php index.py etc)
4. Disable Directory browsing :)
   Now when the root of a folder is accessed without a direct page, it will check all the default names you have specified and display the one that it sees first.

See this link:
https://tecadmin.net/set-default-document-in-iis/

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I am in mvc project and I think I don't have a default page?

Answer (score -1):

Did you get 403.14？ I think your problem is **IIS asp.net extension haven't been installed from "Add role and feature" or turn windows features on or off.**
So no handler would help to handle the MVC routing request.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/scenario-build-an-aspnet-website-on-iis/configuring-step-1-install-iis-and-asp-net-modules

Once you enable the asp.net module, this issue should be fixed. MVC don't depend on either default document or directory browsing.

I also notice that both .release and .debug file are displayed in the root folder. So you just copy the whole project files to your IIS root folder right?

It is suggested to only publish release file to the root folder with VS web deployment tool.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/deploying-to-iis

Comment: hello, in my " turn windows features on or off " inside folder "Application development features" I have just folder " asp " but not "asp.net 4.7"! how to add hem? Thank you ^^

Comment: @hatimazizi yes. You could choose asp.net 4.7. The name of asp.net extension would be different. It can be asp.net 4.5 asp.net 4.8. Please enable these feature and try to access the MVC site again.